# TKinter Layout - New Objects, New Row

Tags: tkinter

How can I organize tkinter's grid so that each object, "leg," has the 5 inputs in 1 row; 4 rows for 4 objects?

As created, it starts a new row with each entry, as imaged: [Tkinter Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Bbg.png)

```
import tkinter as tk

class Calculator:

    def __init__(self,master):

        leg1 = Variables(master)
        leg2 = Variables(master)
        leg3 = Variables(master)
        leg4 = Variables(master)

class Variables(Calculator):

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.qty = tk.Entry(master)
        self.qty.grid(column=0)
        self.expiry = tk.Entry(master)
        self.expiry.grid(column=1)
        self.strike = tk.Entry(master)
        self.strike.grid(column=2)
        self.opt = tk.Entry(master)
        self.opt.grid(column=3)
        self.price = tk.Entry(master)
        self.price.grid(column=4)

root = tk.Tk()
a = Calculator(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have direct control over the row and column numbers. Have you tried explicitly setting the row?

Comment: That's what I'm asking for help on.  setting it inside of Variables writes every object on the same row. I want leg1 on row=0, leg2 on row=1, leg3 on row=2, etc.

Comment: So, what's stopping you from passing in the row number? `leg1 = Variables(master, row=1)`, etc?

Comment: thx Bryan, that did the trick.